# Why does this insert create a copy?

Tags: c++

I was watching [this video](https://youtu.be/ncHmEUmJZf4) on C++ to learn more, and I didn't quite get this explanation [here](https://youtu.be/ncHmEUmJZf4?t=2284) (exact timestamp in the aforementioned video).

Code was

```
void Benchmark_Slow(int iters){
    std::unordered_map<string, int> m;
    std::pair<const string, int> p = {};
    while (iters--) m.insert(p);
//                           ^
// Why does this create a copy?
}
```

He says that the `&&` overload called, instead of the `const &` overload, thus creating a copy. My questions in trying to understand this are,

1. Why does it create a copy? Is it because the argument is not an r-value reference (has a name), and thus cannot be 'constructed-in-place'?
2. Does `m.insert(std::move(p))` fix this?

Comment: You have it backwards. The `const &` overload will be called, not `&&`. Also, in the title you ask about creating a temporary but in the question body you're talking about creating a copy. Which is it?

Comment: Think of it this way: Currently the object is owned by your function and will be destroyed when the function returns. If you want the _same_ object (not a copy) to be stored in the map (which means it has to keep living until removed from the map, not until your function returns), you'll have to transfer its ownership to the map, which you do using `std::move` (which will thereby call the `&&` overload). This is because C++ doesn't have a garbage-collector that would manage the object lifetime otherwise.

Comment: @interjay fixed the title, was thoroughly confused. The speaker says it calls the `&&` overload

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `&&`. That would indicate a move constructor, which should not be able to happen in that case. In any way, the variable `p` is a stack variable within the stack of `Benchmark_Slow`, while the content a map points to must be heap. Thus if this would not copy, *that* would be dubious. Plus, if it would not copy, the map would point several times at the same position in memory, right? That would be bad. If you really want to avoid a copy being called, use a move operation, or better `std::unordered_map::emblace`.

Comment: @Aziuth did you watch the video? The speaker says it calls the 'ref-ref' overload, which I assume is `&&` meaning the move constructor. I seek clarification to why it does copy as the speaker says.

Comment: After taking a small look at the video (not gonna watch the whole one hour thing), I think it might be that an *additional* copy is made. That is aside from the copy that is necessary. Your question should include the better code the guy in the video provides. I *think* (not sure) what this is about is that since `p` is not `const`, it does not fit in a signature that wants a `const std::pair<...>&` and instead of that constructor calls the move constructor, which means that first the variable is copied, a new object is created and then the copy is moved into the new object.

Comment: With the `const`, it would be a direct call of the copy constructor I suppose? Doesn't quite fit what he says. Not sure about that. But I mean, at *some* point something like a copy has to be done. Maybe you might want test this, instead of having a `std::pair` do it with an own class that has console prints in copy constructor, move constructor, assignment operator etc.

Comment: @Aziuth I think the question is talking about copying vs moving the data of `p`. Since data contains a string, it could be arbitrarily large and certainly not in stack (even if in this code it will be empty string).

Comment: I think you mean `emplace` not `emblace`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the

```cpp
template< class P > 
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( P&& value );
```

overload can take *anything* out of which you can construct a

```cpp
std::pair<const string, int>
```

This includes a `std::pair<const string, int>`, but also say a `std::pair<string, int>` or `std::pair<char *, int>`. As such, I assume the implementation of this `insert()` will always have to construct a fresh `std::pair<const string, int>` internally, including the case where it's called with `std::pair<const string, int>`, hence the (extra) "copy".

Making `p` a `const std::pair<const string, int>` will take the

```
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value );
```

overload and thus won't need the extra copy.